# Access JSON array index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is my code:

```
$url2 = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP,AUD';
  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$jsonrates = json_decode($result, true);

$usd_rate = $jsonrates['USD'];
$gbp_rate = $jsonrates['GBP'];
$aud_rate = $jsonrates['AUD'];
```

`print_r($jsonrates)` 
returns a valid JSON array:

`Array ( [rates] => Array ( [AUD] => 1.6239 [USD] => 1.1342 [GBP] => 0.89655 ) [base] => EUR [date] => 2020-07-09 )`

But if I try to access it using an index e.g.
`echo $usd_rate;` or `echo $jsonrates['USD']` it returns `Notice: Undefined index: USD`

Comment: It's a nested array, the top-level has `rates`, `base` and `date`, so you probably want to use: `$jsonrates['rates']['USD']` or similar

Comment: USD is found in the 'rates' array so I would try 'echo $jsonrates['rates']['USD']'

Answer (score 0):

As @msbit pointed out, 'USD' is in a nested array, so you'll need to access that 'rates' array first:

```php
$url2 = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP,AUD';
  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$jsonrates = json_decode($result, true);

$usd_rate = $jsonrates['rates']['USD'];
$gbp_rate = $jsonrates['rates']['GBP'];
$aud_rate = $jsonrates['rates']['AUD'];
```

Comment: Yes, thank you both, it was exactly that, also wasn't sure how to access multi-dimensional array in php, so it's really helpful!